# Programming Riddle: How might you translate an Excel column name to a number?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I was recently asked in a job interview to resolve a programming puzzle that I thought it would be interesting to share. It's about translating Excel column letters to actual numbers, if you recall, Excel names its columns with letters from A to Z, and then the sequence goes AA, AB, AC... AZ, BA, BB, etc.

You have to write a function that accepts a string as a parameter (like "AABCCE") and returns the actual column number.

The solution can be in any language.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: hypothetical problems are allowed - see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/
It's community-wiki, let it go.

Comment: @jquery that's irrelevant to the programming concept which the puzzle exposes

Comment: well first off i'd point out that excel already has a formula for this =COLUMN(), and VBA to do it to ;)

Comment: Do I have to encode it back someday? If it wasn't necessary, I'd take the CRC32 of the string (most languages have a CRC32 implementation ready to use). Returns a nice 32-bit number.

Comment: Besides, what about AA versus A? That's a tricky part of the question, if I return `123` from `"ABC"` then `("AA" == "A"); // 00 == 0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code Golf: Numeric equivalent of an Excel column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634427/code-golf-numeric-equivalent-of-an-excel-column-name)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote this ages ago for some Python script:

```py
def index_to_int(index):
    s = 0
    pow = 1
    for letter in index[::-1]:
        d = int(letter,36) - 9
        s += pow * d
        pow *= 26
    # excel starts column numeration from 1
    return s
```

Comment: Possibly a really stupid question, but is there a reason why you went for `d = int(letter,36) - 9` rather than, say, `d = ord(letter)-ord('A') + 1`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly. Most likely I did something with numeral systems back then and so it was first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Maybe because `int(letter,36)-9` is case insensitive?

Answer (score 36):

Sounds like a standard reduce to me:

Python:

```py
def excel2num(x): 
    return reduce(lambda s,a:s*26+ord(a)-ord('A')+1, x, 0)
```

C#:

```cs
int ExcelToNumber(string x) {
    return x.Aggregate(0, (s, c) => s * 26 + c - 'A' + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Read a column name from STDIN and print out its corresponding number:

```
perl -le '$x = $x * 26 - 64 + ord for <> =~ /./g; print $x'
```

Caveats: Assumes ASCII.

**EDIT:** Replaced `"` with `'` so that your shell won't interpolate `$x` in the string.

Comment: case insensitive in 3 more bytes: perl -le "$x = $x * 26 - 64 + ord uc for <> =~ /./g; print $x"

Comment: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "="`
`Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.` (with Perl 5.18.2)

Comment: Ah. I spotted the error. The shell will interpolate the double quoted string; substituting `$x'; that will not work. I'll update the question.

Comment: @zrajm: Your edit fixes the problem on \*nix, but unfortunately breaks it on Windows.  (Since the question was about Excel, I assumed the OP was on Windows, where only `"` quotes are typically understood by command-line programs, including ActiveState's perl.exe.)

Answer (score 5):

Coincidentally I've solved the same problem using javascript

```js
$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function
    var getNumber = function(x) {
        var result = 0;
        var multiplier = 1;
        for ( var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        { 
            var value = ((x[i].charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0)) + 1);
            result = result + value * multiplier;
            multiplier = multiplier * 26;
        }
        return result;
    };
    
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
        var data = $("#number").val();
        $('#answer').text(getNumber(data));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="number"></input>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

```
    var getNumber = function(x) {
        var result = 0;
        var multiplier = 1;
        for ( var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        { 
            var value = ((x[i].charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0)) + 1);
            result = result + value * multiplier;
            multiplier = multiplier * 26;
        }
        return result;
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Xty/1/

Answer (score 4):

Hah - written it already in our code base - about 3 different times :(

```
%% @doc Convert an string to a decimal integer
%% @spec b26_to_i(string()) -> integer()

b26_to_i(List) when is_list(List) ->
    b26_to_i(string:to_lower(lists:reverse(List)),0,0).

%% private functions
b26_to_i([], _Power, Value) -> 
    Value;

b26_to_i([H|T],Power,Value)->
    NewValue = case (H > 96) andalso (H < 123) of
                   true ->
                       round((H - 96) * math:pow(26, Power));
                   _    ->
                       exit([H | T] ++ " is not a valid base 26 number")
               end,
    b26_to_i(T, Power + 1, NewValue + Value).
```

The riddle is that it isn't actually a Base26 representation of a number (we are lying to ourselves in our function name here) because there is no 0 in it.

The sequence is:
A, B, C ... Z, AA, AB, AC

and not:
A, B, C ...Z, BA, BB, BC

(the language is Erlang, mais oui).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in C like this:

```c
unsigned int coltonum(char * string)
{
   unsigned result = 0;
   char ch;

   while(ch = *string++)
      result = result * 26 + ch - 'A' + 1;

  return result;
}
```

No error checking, only works for upper case strings, string must be null terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the changes, James.  I'll leave it as you updated it, but in general I avoid assignments inside tests for ease of reading and static checking.  This is certainly more "C" ish, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column A = 1

```c
int GetColumnNumber(string columnName)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int exponent = 0;
  for(int i = columnName.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    sum += (columnName[i] - 'A' + 1) *  (GetPower(26, exponent));
    exponent++;
  }
  return sum;
}

int GetPower(int number, int exponent)
{
  int power = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<exponent; i++)
    power *= number;
  return power;
}
```

Comment: also, I dont think this works, have you tested it with some 3 letter strings?

Comment: It's i-- indeed. and ^should be replaced with a power function.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: both of these versions assume only uppercase letters A to Z.  Anything else causes a miscalculation.  It wouldn't be hard to add a bit of error checking and/or uppercasing to improve them.

Scala

```scala
def excel2Number(excel : String) : Int = 
  (0 /: excel) ((accum, ch) => accum * 26 + ch - 'A' + 1)
```

Haskell

```hs
excel2Number :: String -> Int
excel2Number = flip foldl 0 $ \accum ch -> accum * 26 + fromEnum ch - fromEnum 'A' + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the column number from its name

Java:

```java
public int getColNum (String colName) {

    //remove any whitespace
    colName = colName.trim();

    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(colName);

    //string to lower case, reverse then place in char array
    char chars[] = buff.reverse().toString().toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    int retVal=0, multiplier=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length;i++){
        //retrieve ascii value of character, subtract 96 so number corresponds to place in alphabet. ascii 'a' = 97 
        multiplier = (int)chars[i]-96;
        //mult the number by 26^(position in array)
        retVal += multiplier * Math.pow(26, i);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a column name from an int in Java([read more here](http://mcdrummerman.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/convert-a-column-number-to-a-column-name-java-example/#more-146)):

```java
public String getColName (int colNum) {

   String res = "";

   int quot = colNum;
   int rem;        
    /*1. Subtract one from number.
    *2. Save the mod 26 value.
   *3. Divide the number by 26, save result.
   *4. Convert the remainder to a letter.
   *5. Repeat until the number is zero.
   *6. Return that bitch...
   */
    while(quot > 0)
    {
        quot = quot - 1;
        rem = quot % 26;
        quot = quot / 26;

        //cast to a char and add to the beginning of the string
        //add 97 to convert to the correct ascii number
        res = (char)(rem+97) + res;            
    }   
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Delphi one:

```
function ExcelColumnNumberToLetter(col: Integer): string;
begin
  if (col <= 26) then begin
    Result := Chr(col + 64);
  end
  else begin
    col := col-1;
    Result := ExcelColumnNumberToLetter(col div 26) + ExcelColumnNumberToLetter((col mod 26) + 1);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Java:

```
public static int convertNameToIndex(String columnName) {
    int index = 0;
    char[] name = columnName.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        index *= 26;
        index += name[i] - 'A' + 1;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Java solution -->

```
public class ColumnName {

public static int colIndex(String col)
{   int index=0;
    int mul=0;
    for(int i=col.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   
        index  += (col.charAt(i)-64) * Math.pow(26, mul);
        mul++;
    }
    return index;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(colIndex("AAA"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to think of the string as the reverse of the column number in base 26 with digits represented by A, B, ... Z?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. 26 (base 10) equals 10 (base 26) but it is Z in Hexavigesimal, the numbering system described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a number in base 26, with the difference that the number doesn't use 0-9 and then letters but **only** letters.

Comment: No, not true - there is no zero in it

Comment: Right, "A" != "AA" but "0" = "00".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CFML one:

```
<cffunction name="ColToNum" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfargument name="Input" type="String" />
    <cfset var Total = 0 />
    <cfset var Pos = 0 />

    <cfloop index="Pos" from="1" to="#Len(Arguments.Input)#">
        <cfset Total += 26^(Pos-1) * ( Asc( UCase( Mid(Arguments.Input,Pos,1) ) ) - 64 ) />
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn Total />
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>
    #ColToNum('AABCCE')#
</cfoutput>
```

And because I'm in an odd mood, here's a CFScript version:

```
function ColToNum ( Input )
{
    var Total = 0;

    for ( var Pos = 1 ; Pos <= Len(Arguments.Input) ; Pos++ )
    {
        Total += 26^(Pos-1) * ( Asc( UCase( Mid(Arguments.Input,Pos,1) ) ) - 64 );
    }

    return Total;
}

WriteOutput( ColToNum('AABCCE') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp:

```cl
(defun excel->number (string)
  "Converts an Excel column name to a column number."
  (reduce (lambda (a b) (+ (* a 26) b))
          string
          :key (lambda (x) (- (char-int x) 64))))
```

*edit:* the inverse operation:

```cl
(defun number->excel (number &optional acc)
  "Converts a column number to Excel column name."
  (if (zerop number)
      (concatenate 'string acc)
      (multiple-value-bind (rest current) (floor number 26)
        (if (zerop current)
            (number->excel (- rest 1) (cons #\Z acc))
            (number->excel rest (cons (code-char (+ current 64)) acc))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly related, the better challenge is the other way around: given the column number, find the column label as string.

Qt version as what I implemented for KOffice:

```cpp
QString columnLabel( unsigned column )
{
  QString str;
  unsigned digits = 1;
  unsigned offset = 0;

  column--;
  for( unsigned limit = 26; column >= limit+offset; limit *= 26, digits++ )
    offset += limit;

  for( unsigned c = column - offset; digits; --digits, c/=26 )
    str.prepend( QChar( 'A' + (c%26) ) );

  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another [more cryptic] erlang example:

```
col2int(String) -> col2int(0,String).
col2int(X,[A|L]) when A >= 65, A =< 90 ->
col2int(26 * X + A - 65 + 1, L);
col2int(X,[]) -> X.
```

and inverse function:

```
int2col(Y) when Y > 0 -> int2col(Y,[]).
int2col(0,L) -> L;
int2col(Y,L) when Y rem 26 == 0 -> 
   int2col(Y div 26 - 1,[(26+65-1)|L]);
int2col(Y,L) ->
   P = Y rem 26,
   int2col((Y - P) div 26,[P + 65-1|L]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi:

```
// convert EXcel column name to column number 1..256
// case-sensitive; returns 0 for illegal column name
function cmColmAlfaToNumb( const qSRC : string ) : integer;
var II : integer;
begin
   result := 0;
   for II := 1 to length(qSRC) do begin
      if (qSRC[II]<'A')or(qSRC[II]>'Z') then begin
         result := 0;
         exit;
      end;
      result := result*26+ord(qSRC[II])-ord('A')+1;
   end;
   if result>256 then result := 0;
end;
```

-Al.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def ExcelColumnToNumber(ColumnName):
    ColNum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(ColumnName)):
        # Easier once formula determined: 'PositionValue * Base^Position'
        # i.e. AA=(1*26^1)+(1*26^0)   or  792=(7*10^2)+(9*10^1)+(2*10^0)
        ColNum += (int(ColumnName[i],36) -9) * (pow(26, len(ColumnName)-i-1))
    return ColNum
```

p.s. My first Python script!

Answer (score 0):

This version is purely functional and permits alternative 'code' sequences, for example if you wanted to only uses the letters 'A' to 'C'. In Scala, with a suggestion from dcsobral.

```scala
def columnNumber(name: String) = {
    val code = 'A' to 'Z'

    name.foldLeft(0) { (sum, letter) =>
        (sum * code.length) + (code.indexOf(letter) + 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica:

```
FromDigits[ToCharacterCode@# - 64, 26] &
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mr. Wizard's awesome Mathematica code, but getting rid of the cryptic pure function!

```
columnNumber[name_String] := FromDigits[ToCharacterCode[name] - 64, 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has good explanations and algos

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal

```
public static String toBase26(int value){
    // Note: This is a slightly modified version of the Alphabet-only conversion algorithm

    value = Math.abs(value);
    String converted = "";

    boolean iteration = false;

    // Repeatedly divide the number by 26 and convert the
    // remainder into the appropriate letter.
    do {
        int remainder = value % 26;

        // Compensate for the last letter of the series being corrected on 2 or more iterations.
        if (iteration && value < 25) {
            remainder--;
        }

        converted = (char)(remainder + 'A') + converted;
        value = (value - remainder) / 26;

        iteration = true;
    } while (value > 0);

    return converted;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

…just needed a solution for **PHP**. This is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * Calculates the column number for a given column name.
 *
 * @param string $columnName the column name: "A", "B", …, "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB" … "AZ", "BA", … "ZZ", "AAA", …
 *
 * @return int the column number for the given column name: 1 for "A", 2 for "B", …, 25 for "Y", 26 for "Z", 27 for "AA", … 52 for "AZ", 53 for "BA", … 703 for "AAA", …
 */
function getColumnNumber($columnName){
    //  the function's result
    $columnNumber = 0;

    //  at first we need to lower-case the string because we calculate with the ASCII value of (lower-case) "a"
    $columnName = strtolower($columnName);
    //  ASCII value of letter "a"
    $aAsciiValue = ord('a') - 1;

    //  iterate all characters by splitting the column name
    foreach (str_split($columnName) as $character) {
        //  determine ASCII value of current character and substract with that one from letter "a"
        $characterNumberValue = ord($character) - $aAsciiValue;

        //  through iteration and multiplying we finally get the previous letters' values on base 26
        //  then we just add the current character's number value
        $columnNumber = $columnNumber * 26 + $characterNumberValue;
    }

    //  return the result
    return $columnNumber;
}
```

Of course the script can be shortened a little by just combining some stuff into one line of code within the foreach loop:

```
//  …
$columnNumber = $columnNumber * 26 + ord($character) - ord('a') + 1;
//  …
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, without reduce:

```
def transform(column_string):
    return sum((ascii_uppercase.index(letter)+1) * 26**position for position, letter in enumerate(column_string[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of this code in Python:

```py
keycode=1
for i in range (1,len(word)):
    numtest[i]=word[i-1]
    keycode = keycode*26*int(wordtest[numtest[i]])
last=word[-1:]
keycode=keycode+int(wordtest[last])
print(keycode)
print(bin(keycode))
#Numtest and wordtest are dictionaries.
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I removed the new question from this answer.  If you want to ask a new question, please open a new question.

Comment: The answer is edit after putting an post on SO Meta [`Link`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308227/how-to-flag-a-post-which-contains-both-answer-and-a-new-question/308228#308228).