# increasing string size through loop

Tags: python, string

what's a simple way to increase the length of a string to an arbitrary integer x? like 'a' goes to 'z' and then goes to 'aa' to 'zz' to 'aaa', etc.

Comment: Where does `x` come in? Like if the string is "abc" and `x` is 4, the string becomes "abg"?

Comment: oops. i meant to say the string becomes x long, so if x = 4, the strings would be 'aaaa'... 'zzzz'

Comment: Somewhat related, see [this code golf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634427/code-golf-numeric-equivalent-of-an-excel-column-name/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
def iterate_strings(n):
    if n <= 0:
        yield ''
        return
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        for s in iterate_strings(n - 1):
            yield c + s
```

It returns a generator.
You can iterate it with a for loop:

```
for s in iterate_strings(5)
```

Or get a list of the strings:

```
list(iterate_strings(5))
```

If you want to iterate over shorter strings too, you can use this function:

```
def iterate_strings(n):
    yield ''
    if n <= 0:
        return
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        for s in iterate_strings(n - 1):
            yield c + s
```

Comment: Fixed the backwards going problem.
Vote for my answer please :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution, similar to Adam's, except it's not recursive. `:]`.

```
from itertools import product
from string import lowercase

def letter_generator(limit):
    for length in range(1, limit+1):
        for letters in product(lowercase, repeat=length):
            yield ''.join(letters)
```

And it returns a `generator`, so you can use a `for` loop to iterate over it:

```
for letters in letter_generator(5):
    # ...
```

Have fun!

(This is the second time today I found `itertools.product()` useful. Woot.)

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the string in the integer.
For example

```
>>> 'a' * 2
'aa'
>>> 'a' * 4
'aaaa'
>>> 'z' * 3
'zzz'
>>> 'az' * 3
'azazaz'
```

Comment: Let's see if I get you right: You want to iterate over all the strings between 'aaaa' and 'zzzz', ('aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', .... 'zzzz').

Answer (score 0):

Define x. I am using `x = 5` for this example.

```
x = 5
import string
for n in range(1,x+1):
  for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print letter*n
```

Comment: You might want to set the start value of the range statement since the very first thing printed using that code is 26 lines of blanks because you're doing `letter*0` at first.