# How to convert numbers to an alpha numeric system with php

Tags: php

I'm not sure what this is called, which is why I'm having trouble searching for it.

What I'm looking to do is to take numbers and convert them to some alphanumeric base so that the number, say 5000, wouldn't read as '5000' but as 'G4u', or something like that. The idea is to save space and also not make it obvious how many records there are in a given system. I'm using php, so if there is something like this built into php even better, but even a name for this method would be helpful at this point.

Again, sorry for not being able to be more clear, I'm just not sure what this is called.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php).

Comment: You might find [`Alphabet::convert($number, Alphabet::DECIMAL, Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-BaseConvert) useful, which can also be used with `Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC_HUMAN` or any custom alphabet you specify. It works on arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funnily enough, I asked [the exact opposite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982112/encoding-arbitrary-data-into-numbers) yesterday.

The first thing that comes to mind is converting your decimal number into [hexadecimal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php). 5000 would turn into `1388`, 10000 into `2710`. Will save a few bytes here and there.

You could also use a higher base that utilizes the full alphabet (0-Z instead of 0-F) or even the full 256 ASCII characters. As @Yacoby points out, you can use `base_convert()` for that.

As I said in the comment, keep in mind that this is not an efficient way to mask IDs. If you have a security problem when people can guess the next or previous ID to a record, this is very poor protection.

Comment: there are no security implications, just cosmetic, base_convert is the answer that looks like itll work. Thanks all for the help and insight though!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#105990 will also allow for expanding number of characters used, for example upper-case ones as well.

Comment: While a *byte* can represent 256 possible values, *ASCII* only has 128 characters.

Answer (score 8):

You want to change the base of the number to something other than base 10 (I think you want base 36 as it uses the entire alphabet and numbers 0 - 9).

The inbuilt [base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function may help, although it does have the limitation it can only convert between bases 2 and 36

```
$number = '5000';
echo base_convert($number, 10, 36); //3uw
```

Comment: @Patrick this would also be my way to go. Just remember that you're not really hiding/protecting anything in your site by cloaking the numbers. And anyone can easily figure out that you are base36'ing the numbers. But this would be the way to go. Code examples here: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/converter.html

Comment: And PHP docs for base_covert have a comment with "A simple function to convert an int to any base." That way i can expand it to treat a-z and A-Z as distinct cases, giving me 62 district options instead of 36.

Answer (score 2):

[dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) will convert a number to hex for you.  It won't obfuscate how many records are in a given system, however. I don't think it will make it any more efficient to store or save space, either.

You'd probably want to use a 2 way crypt function if obfuscation is needed. That won't save space, either.

Please state your goals more clearly and give more background, because this seems a bit pointless as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This might confuse more people than simply converting the base of the numbers ...

Try using signed digits to represent your numbers.  For example, instead of using digits 0..9 for decimal numbers, use digits -5..5.  This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed-digit_representation) gives an example for the binary representation of numbers, but the approach can be used for any numeric base.

Using this together with, say, base-36 arithmetic might satisfy you.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: This answer is not really a solution to the question, so ignore it unless you are trying to hash a number.

My first thought we be to hash it using eg. [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) or [sha1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php). (You'd probably not save any space though...)

To prevent people from using [rainbow-tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) or [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) to guess which number you hashed, you can always add a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). It can be as simple as a string prepended to your number before hashing it.

md5 would return an alphanumeric string of exactly 32 chars and sha1 would return one of exaclty 40 chars.

Comment: He'd obviously still **want** to know what the original number was. The idea is to save disc space, so it needs to be reversible.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't save any space (the opposite, actually) and you wouldn't be able to get the original number back from the hash.

Comment: Sorry, guess I misunderstood him.