# converting a number base 10 to base 62 (a-zA-Z0-9)

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, numeric, alphanumeric

I have a number in base 10. Is there anyway to translate it to a base 62?

Example:

```
echo convert(12324324);
// returns Yg3 (fantasy example here)
```

PHP's [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/base_convert) can convert up to base 36.

Comment: So you want to convert base 10 to base 24, using all characters from A-Z?

Comment: Should "11" gets converted to "aa" or "k"?

Comment: @KingCrunch better if it converts to k

Comment: @Pekka yes all chars A-Z, it would be even nicer with it could use with upper case too, like a-z and A-Z (48 chars)

Comment: @jnpcl I need space saving (example: bit.ly urls)

Comment: @yes123: And how this conversion may save space?

Comment: Question [#2985316](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985316/how-to-convert-numbers-to-alpha-numeric-system-with-php) may have some good info for you.

Comment: @yes123 @Pekka you do realize that the normal English alphabet has 26 characters?

Comment: @Patrick ah, I stand corrected. (Both my native alphabets have more, which is why I tend to forget :)

Comment: @jnpcl thanks! i added a comment in my first post. At this point let's try to make a function to use uppercase too (so converting to base 62 )

Comment: You might want to take a look at [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**OLD**: A quick and dirty solution can be to use a function like this:

```
function toChars($number) {
   $res = base_convert($number, 10,26);
   $res = strtr($res,'0123456789','qrstuvxwyz');
   return $res;
}
```

The base convert translate your number to a base where the digits are 0-9a-p
then you get rid of the remaining digits with a quick char substitution.

As you may observe, the function is easily reversible.

```
function toNum($number) {
   $res = strtr($number,'qrstuvxwyz','0123456789');
   $res = base_convert($number, 26,10);
   return $res;
}
```

By the way, what would you use this function for?

---

**Edit:**

Based on the question change and on the @jnpcl answer, here is a set of functions that performs the base conversion without using pow and log (they take half the time to complete the tests).

The functions work for integer values only.

```
function toBase($num, $b=62) {
  $base='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $r = $num  % $b ;
  $res = $base[$r];
  $q = floor($num/$b);
  while ($q) {
    $r = $q % $b;
    $q =floor($q/$b);
    $res = $base[$r].$res;
  }
  return $res;
}

function to10( $num, $b=62) {
  $base='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $limit = strlen($num);
  $res=strpos($base,$num[0]);
  for($i=1;$i<$limit;$i++) {
    $res = $b * $res + strpos($base,$num[$i]);
  }
  return $res;
}
```

The test:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
  $x =  toBase($i);
  $y =  to10($x);
  if ($i-$y)
    echo "\n$i -> $x -> $y";
}
```

Comment: Its explained in the comments of the question.

Comment: Just seen the modified question. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Your toBase function appears to return a slightly different result than the one built into php for bases below 36. Why is that?

Comment: @Mike Have you some input samples to let me test the behaviour?

Comment: I just figured out my problem. PHP's mod function apparently has issues with numbers over 2^31. Using the bcmod function fixed the problem.

Comment: Isn't there a '(' missing on this line:  $base='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

Comment: @ToddB: you are correcyt. Fixed

Comment: Yeah, well working: http://codepad.org/Lj9qRd2n (I removed the `if($i-$y)` check)

Comment: This "quick and dirty" solution doesn't do what's asked and isn't reversible. The question was to code in Base 62.

Comment: @DanHorvat The quick and dirty solution was aimed to answer the original question. Why do you think it is not reversible? Have you any number (>2^31) that fails the test of going through toChars and toNum functions without remain unchanged?

Comment: @Eineki Thanks, works great using this logic in C# https://gist.github.com/herman1vdb/8c0677120f67e5f4a8a6 , (only need it for positive integers... :D)

Comment: Perhaps http://www.lalit.org/lab/base62-php-convert-number-to-base-62-for-short-urls/ could provide a better solution.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut I have problem for number higher than `2147483648`. how to use this function for higher than this?   I try http://www.lalit.org/lab/base62-php-convert-number-to-base-62-for-short-urls/   but this class have this problem.

Comment: @mghhgm  I need more details to be of any help. I can just guess it is a type casting issue: 2147483648 is a peculiar number. Have you seen php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php ? Are you using a 32bit system? How it misbehave? Try to change the line occurence of `$num % $b` with `fmod($num, $b)` and `$num/$b` (and similar ones) with `intdiv($nub, $b)`. They are slower but, on 32bit system should solve the casting type problem I hope you are facing.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut That's right. I forgot max int support on 32bit is `2147483647`. I test this code on linux server and check this for big number like `123456789876543210` and work correctly! Thank you very much ❤️❤️

Comment: @Eineki this will miss the first character. FOr ex at 62 the result will be encoding will be 10 so entire 0 series 0, 0x, 0xx, 0xxx... is missed by this logic. Any fix for this?

Comment: @AmitTripathi I do not understand your question. Have you a number that misbehave? You should post the base 10 representation of this number, the expected value and the wrong result. Can you post one (or more)?

Answer (score 11):

A simpler (and possibly faster) implementation that does not use `pow` nor `log`:

```
function base62($num) {
  $index = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $res = '';
  do {
    $res = $index[$num % 62] . $res;
    $num = intval($num / 62);
  } while ($num);
  return $res;
}
```

Comment: It is similar indeed (just replace `62` with `$b`), I read the answers too fast, just a little less verbose. My comparison was with methods that use `pow` and `log`, which are known to be slow, and that comparison has been done in Eineki’s answer. You can delete this one, since it does not provide substantial new information.

Comment: For big numbers using bcmath:

`bcscale(0);
do {
 $res = $index[bcmod($q,62)].$res;
 $q = bcdiv($q,62);
} while ($q);
bcscale(3);`

Answer (score 8):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450

```
<?php
// Decimal > Custom
function dec2any( $num, $base=62, $index=false ) {
    if (! $base ) {
        $base = strlen( $index );
    } else if (! $index ) {
        $index = substr( "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ,0 ,$base );
    }
    $out = "";


    // this fix partially breaks when $num=0, but fixes the $num=238328 bug
    // also seems to break (adds a leading zero) at $num=226981 through $num=238327 *shrug*
    // for ( $t = floor( log10( $num ) / log10( $base - 1 ) ); $t >= 0; $t-- ) {

    // original code:
    for ( $t = floor( log10( $num ) / log10( $base ) ); $t >= 0; $t-- ) {
        $a = floor( $num / pow( $base, $t ) );
        $out = $out . substr( $index, $a, 1 );
        $num = $num - ( $a * pow( $base, $t ) );
    }
    return $out;
}
?>
```

> Parameters:

> `$num` - your decimal integer

> `$base` - base to which you wish to convert `$num` (leave it 0 if you are providing `$index` or omit if you're using the default (62))

> `$index` - if you wish to use the default list of digits (0-1a-zA-Z), omit this option, otherwise provide a string (ex.: "zyxwvu")

```
<?php
// Custom > Decimal
function any2dec( $num, $base=62, $index=false ) {
    if (! $base ) {
        $base = strlen( $index );
    } else if (! $index ) {
        $index = substr( "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0, $base );
    }
    $out = 0;
    $len = strlen( $num ) - 1;
    for ( $t = 0; $t <= $len; $t++ ) {
        $out = $out + strpos( $index, substr( $num, $t, 1 ) ) * pow( $base, $len - $t );
    }
    return $out;
}
?>
```

> Parameters:

> `$num` - your custom-based number (string) (ex.: "11011101")

> `$base` - base with which `$num` was encoded (leave it 0 if you are providing `$index` or omit if you're using default (62))

> `$index` - if you wish to use the default list of digits (0-1a-zA-Z), omit this option, otherwise provide a string (ex.: "abcdef")

Comment: it doesnt' work for only 1 number: it's 238328. dec2any(238328) returns "00" and any2dec("00") returns 0.  DAMN

Comment: because of "pow( $base, $len - $t );" in the any2dec

Comment: yes, we could add an if in the any2dec to fix this bug, but it's not elegant, anyway i think i have found another function that works 100% but it seems to be slower. if you fix it in an elegant way write here :)

Comment: try to use the base10 conversion without using pow in my answer. I'm not sure my dec2any version is quicker than jnpci one

Comment: I found a "fix" for the `238328` case, but it seems to break in other places. I don't understand the math behind the algorithm, so I have no idea why it works. Edited my code above.

Answer (score 3):

For big numbers, you might want to use the PHP BC library

```php
function intToAny( $num, $base = null, $index = null ) {
    if ( $num <= 0 ) return '0';
    if ( ! $index )
        $index = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if ( ! $base )
        $base = strlen( $index );
    else
        $index = substr( $index, 0, $base );
    $res = '';
    while( $num > 0 ) {
        $char = bcmod( $num, $base );
        $res .= substr( $index, $char, 1 );
        $num = bcsub( $num, $char );
        $num = bcdiv( $num, $base );
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: $res .= substr( $index, $char, 1 );  should be 
$res = substr( $index, $char, 1 ) . $res;

Comment: I tried to convert something to base62, and then convert it back to base10. It returned a 0. So, this is a one-way thing, evidently. Also, it would be nice to use this for providing shortcodes in a website, where I could scramble the $index. However, without reversability, it makes it kind of tough to find an ID in a table unless I use the shortcode as the ID.

Comment: as @Lance Rushing pointed your return is inverted, you can apply his fix or strrev in the final return

Answer (score 3):

This function output the same than [GNU Multiple Precision](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) if possible…

```
<?php

function base_convert_alt($val,$from_base,$to_base){
static $gmp;
static $bc;
static $gmp62;
if ($from_base<37) $val=strtoupper($val);
if ($gmp===null) $gmp=function_exists('gmp_init');
if ($gmp62===null) $gmp62=version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.3.2')>=0;
if ($gmp && ($gmp62 or ($from_base<37 && $to_base<37)))
return gmp_strval(gmp_init($val,$from_base),$to_base);
if ($bc===null) $bc=function_exists('bcscale');
$range='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
if ($from_base==10)
$base_10=$val;
else
{
$n=strlen(($val="$val"))-++$ratio;
if ($bc) for($i=$n;$i>-1;($ratio=bcmul($ratio,$from_base)) && $i--)
$base_10=bcadd($base_10,bcmul(strpos($range,$val[$i]),$ratio));
else for($i=$n;$i>-1;($ratio*=$from_base) && $i--)
$base_10+=strpos($range,$val[$i])*$ratio;
}
if ($bc)
do $result.=$range[bcmod($base_10,$to_base)];
while(($base_10=bcdiv($base_10,$to_base))>=1);
else
do $result.=$range[$base_10%$to_base];
while(($base_10/=$to_base)>=1);
return strrev($to_base<37?strtolower($result):$result);
}


echo base_convert_alt('2661500360',7,51);

// Output Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function convertBase10ToBase62($num){
    $charset="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $endChar=$charset[$num%62];
    $rtn="";

    if ( $num == "62" ) { 
        $rtn=$rtn.$charset[1]; 
    } else if ( $num >= 62 ) { 
        $rtn=$rtn.$charset[intval($num/62)%62+1]; 
    }

    $num=intval($num/62);

    while ($num > 61) {
        if ( is_int($num/62) == true ) { 
            $rtn=$rtn.$charset[0]; 
        } else { 
            $rtn=$rtn.$charset[$num%62]; 
        }

        $num=intval($num/62);
    }
    $rtn=$rtn.$endChar;
    echo "\n";
    echo $rtn;

    return $rtn;
}
```

Comment: I think this dont work: convertBase10ToBase62(11942787908393) -> "qpYq5goH" (should be "3og5qYpH")

Answer (score 2):

If you have gmp extension:

```
gmp_strval(gmp_init($x, 10), 62)
```

Comment: probably the best answer

Answer (score 1):

have an array of characters like:

```
$chars = array(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    //....
    27 => 'A',
    28 => 'B'
);

function getCharacter($key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $chars[$key]))
        return $chars[$key];
    return false;
}

function getNumber($char)
{
    return array_search($char, $chars);
}
```

Comment: `$chars = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A,'Z'));` I like `range()` :)

Answer (score 1):

It was hardly tested and works on real big product.
Just copy this functions and use. 
**If needed, you can arrange $baseChars sequentially, I need it for blended.**

```
    /**
     * decToAny converter
     * 
     * @param integer $num
     * @param string $baseChars
     * @param integer $base
     * @return string
     */
    function decToAny($num, $baseChars = '', $base = 62, $index = false) {

        $baseChars = empty($baseChars) ? 'HbUlYmGoAd0ScKq6Er5PuZp3OsQCh4RfNMtV8kJiLv9yXeI1aWgFj2zTx7DnBw' : $baseChars;
        if (!$base) {
            $base = strlen($index);
        } else if (!$index) {
            $index = substr($baseChars, 0, $base);
        }
        $out = "";

        for ($t = floor(log10($num) / log10($base)); $t >= 0; $t--) {
            $a = floor($num / pow($base, $t));
            $out = $out . substr($index, $a, 1);
            $num = $num - ( $a * pow($base, $t) );
        }

        return $out;
    }
```

Reverse method

```
    /**
     * anyTodec converter
     * 
     * @param string $num
     * @param string $baseChars
     * @param integer $base
     * @return string
     */
    function anyToDec($num, $baseChars = '', $base = 62, $index = false) {

        $baseChars = empty($baseChars) ? 'HbUlYmGoAd0ScKq6Er5PuZp3OsQCh4RfNMtV8kJiLv9yXeI1aWgFj2zTx7DnBw' : $baseChars;
        if (!$base) {
            $base = strlen($index);
        } else if (!$index) {
            $index = substr($baseChars, 0, $base);
        }
        $out = 0;
        $len = strlen($num) - 1;
        for ($t = 0; $t <= $len; $t++) {
            $out = $out + strpos($index, substr($num, $t, 1)) * pow($base, $len - $t);
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertBase10ToBase62($num){
$charset="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$rtn="";

$n=$num;$base=62;
while($n>0){
    $temp=$n%$base;
    $rtn=$charset[$temp].$rtn;
    $n=intval($n/$base);
}
 return $rtn;
}
```