# Create a List of string in ascending Order in lexicographically order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I want to generate a algorithm in which I want to get the next string  in lexicographically order.

Suppose I want to generate a list of length 26 then it is

```
['a','b'....'z']
```

Now suppose I want to generate a list of length 260 then it is

```
['a0','a1','a2'...'a9','b1'....'z0'....'z9']
```

This type of algorithm have max-limit. But I don't want such type of limitations. It may be 10000 or 1 millions.

**Requirement**

Algorithm should work in such a way that previously string is passed as argument generate by it. And it should produce the next string in lexicographically order. And I do not want to use timestamp (1503314045645)

Thanks

Comment: Since incrementing the string isn't as useful in real life, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356549/auto-incrementing-alphanumeric-sequence/43358781#43358781

Comment: what is the character set? Also, in 1st case, y not `['a', 'aa',...,'aaa...aaa(26 times)']`? (I believe `aa` is lexically smaller than `b`)

Answer (score 0):

What about using base 36 formatted integers?
It looks like this in java:

```
String next(String prev) {
  if(prev==null) {
    return "0";
  }
  return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(prev, 36), 36);
}
```

Actually it's even better if you you use a simple integer for storing the value, and simply increase it every time you need the next value and format the integer using base 36 into a string:

```
Integer.toString(++value, 36);
```

In this solution the numbers are before the letters in the output, so you will get the following tokens:
a7,a8,a9,aa,ab, ... ax,ay,az,b0,b1 ... zx,zy,zz,100,101

If you want letters first or want any specific order or extra characters, then use the solution behind Matt Timmermans' link.