# PHP encoding to only have letters and numbers

Tags: php

Is there a encoding function in PHP which will encode strings and the resulting output will only contain letters and numbers? I would use base64 but that still has some stuff which is not numeric/alphanumeric

Comment: What is it for ? I think it can be a specific answer.

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago: [Encoding arbitrary data into numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982112/encoding-arbitrary-data-into-numbers) I haven't had the time yet to test the answers, but @Artefacto's looks excellent

Comment: Convert all characters to their ASCII codes using ord() ?

Comment: It seems [`Alphabet::convert($str, Alphabet::BYTE, Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-BaseConvert) may be what you want, i.e. the alphabet of base *62*. You could restrict this to just lowercase (`Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC_LOWERCASE`) or uppercase (`Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC_UPPERCASE`) as well, but that would produce longer outputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use base32 (code easy to google), which is sort of a standard alternative to base64. Or resort to [bin2hex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and `pack("H*",$hex)` to reverse. Hex encoding however leads to size doubling.

Comment: (but if its of any significant size, and starting off as text, you can compress it first!)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, base64 uses a reduced set of output chars compared with uuencode and was intended to solve most character converions issues - but still isn't url-safe (IIRC).

But the machanism is trivial and easily adapted - I'd suggest having a look at [base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) encoding - same as base64 but using one less bit per input char to create the output (and hence a 32 char alphabet is all that's required) but using something different for the padding char ('=' is not url safe).

A quick google found [this](http://xref.moodle.org/nav.html?lib/base32.php.source.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any of the hash functions (md5, sha1, etc.) output will only consist of hexadecimal digits but that's not exactly 'encoding'.

Comment: Don't want to hash because it needs to be recoverable.

Comment: I know it's an additional step but can't you hash the string again when you need to recover the key for the APC cache?

Comment: Why does an APC key need to be recoverable? It's a cache, fetching with a one-way encoding seems pretty OK to me?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own base-62 encoder/decoder using a-z/A-Z/0-9. You'd need 3 digits for every ASCII character though, so not that efficient.

Comment: Why would he need 3 digits? Surely 2 would suffice.

Comment: I'm getting myself confused on this, but I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to use letters, numbers and dashes.

I'm sure you can improve it to take out the dashes:

```
function pj_code($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    while ($len--) {
        $enc .= base_convert(ord(substr($str,$len,1)),10,36) . '-';
    }
    return $enc;
}


function pj_decode($str) {
    $ords = explode('-',$str);
    $c = count($ords);
    while ($c--) {
        $dec .= chr(base_convert($ords[$c],36,10));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the basic [md5](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) hash function which output only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Yeah, and its counterpart `md5_decode()` ;) Seriously though, it looks like the OP is looking for an encode / decode pair, not a hashing function

Comment: that's not an answer, if you don't like to invest the time for a real answer, don't post. This is SO, not some kind of forum.

Comment: @tharkun: sorry about that. I thought it was enough as the md5 documentation is clear. I edited my answer.