# How to generate a 128-bit long string?

Tags: php, random

Basically, I'm looking for a function to perform the following

```
generateToken(128)
```

which will return a 128-bit **string** consisting of integers or alphabet characters.

Clarification: From the comments, I had to change the question. Apparently, I am looking for a string that is 16 characters long if it needs to be 128 bits.

Comment: what is to have 128-bits? the number of the string representation?

Comment: Axsuul, your response doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you mean you want a 128-bit number encoded as a string, or do you want a number with 128 digits? I've assumed you want a 128-bit number in my answer.

Comment: @Cameron A number with 128 digits is different from a number with 128 bits. A number with 128 bits is something between 0 and 2^128-1. I asked whether he wanted a random number between 0 and 2^128-1 or a string with 128/8=16 characters.

Comment: @Artefacto: Yes, I know. That's why I asked for clarification: does the OP want 128 bits or 128 decimal digits?

Comment: @Artefacto: Or I guess he could want a 16-character string (i.e. a 16-digit number in this case).

Comment: Yes, sorry for any confusion, but I really just wanted a 16-character string (or 16 digit number).  That is, not a 128-bit number.  Could one of you explain why 128/8 = 16 characters is 128 bits and I will accept that answer? I will also edit my question. Thanks again

Comment: A 16 character string may not be 128 bits, if it's in a multibyte encoding like UTF-8 and at least one of the characters is outside the 0-127 bits (ASCII) range. But a 16-byte string is 128 bits, since 1 byte=8 bits (8*16=128).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason you must restrict the string to integers? That actually makes the problem a lot harder because each digit gives you 3.3 bits (because 2^3.3 ~= 10). It's tricky to generate exactly 128 bits of token in this manner.

Much easier is to allow hexadecimal encoding (4 bits per character). You can then generate 128 genuine random bits, then encode them in hex for use in your application. Base64 encoding (6 bits per character) is also useful for this kind of thing.

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` will give you a string of random bytes that you can use `bin2hex` to encode, otherwise you can use `mt_rand` in your own token-generation routine.

EDIT: After reading the updates to the question it seems that you want to generate a token that represents 128 bits of data and the actual string length (in characters) is not so important. If I guess your intention correctly (that this is a unique ID, possibly for identification/authentication purposes) then I'd suggest you use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` to generate the right number of bits for your problem, in this case 128 (16 bytes). You can then encode those bits in any way you see fit: hex and base64 are two possibilities.

Note that hex encoding will use 32 characters to encode 128 bits of data since each character only encodes 4 bits (128 / 4 = 32). Base64 will use 22 characters (128 / 6 = 21.3). Each character takes up 8 bits of *storage* but only encodes 4 or 6 bits of *information*.

Be very careful not to confuse encoded string length with raw data length. If you choose a 16-character string using alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) then you only get 6 bits of information per character (log base 2 of 62 is nearly 6), so your 16-character string will only encode 96 bits of information. You should think of your token as an opaque byte array and only worry about turning it into / from a character string when you actually try to send it over the wire or put it in a cookie or whatever.

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` doesn't give a hex-encoded representation. Anyway, it is a good solution. After that, it's just a matter of using e.g. bcmath to build the number in base 10 string representation.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misread the example and left out the `bin2hex` bit :)

Comment: relevant: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982112/encoding-arbitrary-data-into-numbers/3402951#3402951 for how to convert arbitrary data into numbers in base 10.

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3:

```
$rand128 = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

Comment: And with PHP 7.0+, it’s simply `random_bytes` instead of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose?

If you just want a unique id, then use uniqid:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Its not random, its essentially a hex string based on microtime. If you do uniqid('', true), then it will return a hex string based on microtime as well as tack on a bunch of random numbers on the end of the id (so even if two calls come in on the same microsecond, it is unlikely that they'll share a unique id).

If you need a 16-character string exactly, then what purpose? Are you salting passwords? How random should the string be? All in all, you can always just do:

```
$toShow = array();
for($i = 0; $i<16; $i++){
    $toShow[] = chr(mt_rand(ord('a'), ord('z')));
}
return $toShow
```

Now this creates a string of characters that are between 'a' and 'z'. You can change "ord('a')" to 0, and "ord('z')" to 255 to get a fully random binary string... or any other range you need.