# PHP 64 bit Random Number

Tags: php

does anyone know a simple way to generate a random 64 bit number using PHP? It would be best if it doesn't rely on any extensions if possible.

Comment: Maybe this link can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523343/how-do-you-generate-a-random-number-over-the-32bit-limit-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a bunch of smaller (16 bits) random numbers using [mt_rand](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and combine them. This approach is also used in [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#69164) UUID example on php.net.

Comment: That seemed to work. Although, when I converted it using `base_convert` it was too large? I think it might be a problem with the precision of that function?

Answer (score 4):

Fetch 8 random bytes from /dev/urandom or some equivalent source.

Comment: how? could use a little more on this answer

Comment: It's a file... `$fp = fopen('/dev/urandom'); fread($fp, 8); fclose($fp);`

Comment: or try: `$rnd = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, 8);`

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
rand(0, 18446744073709551615)
```

From [the php documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

> On some platforms (such as Windows), getrandmax() is only 32768. If you require a range larger than 32768, specifying min and max will allow you to create a range larger than this, or consider using mt_rand() instead.

Comment: This works for `mt_rand` too, but it only returns values different from 0 for smaller numbers than the one given above.

Comment: This gives "Warning: rand() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in - on line 1" on PHP 7.

Comment: Also, the results may not be distributed evenly: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63174#1437000589

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand64bit = rand() << 32 | rand();
```