# Encode string into decimal digits - javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding

Is there a way to encode regular javascript utf-8 string into decimal 0-9 ( or octal 0-7 if that's more convenient) (octal or base10) ?

I saw this thread for php, I want similar for javascript.

[Encoding byte data into digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982112/encoding-byte-data-into-digits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this exactly, but depending on your needs, it's easy enough.  JavaScript's `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` returns the numeric Unicode value of the characters in a string, which can go up to 65,536 (assuming your are not using unicode codepoints > 0x10000; if you are, [consult the `String.prototype.charCodeAt` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)).

Chances are, you're using ASCII, meaning your numeric character codes will be, at most, 255, meaning you could get by with three digits.  So first we'll need a function to pad zeros:

```
function zeroPad(n, w){
    while(n.toString().length<w) n = '0' + n;
    return n;
}
```

Then we can create a function to convert your string to a string of numbers:

```
function toNumbers(s){
    var nums = '';
    for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        nums += zeroPad(s.charCodeAt(i), 3);
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Then a function to decode:

```
function fromNumbers(nums){
    var s = '';
    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i+=3){
        console.log(i + ': ' + nums.substring(i, i+3))
        s += String.fromCharCode(nums.substring(i, i+3));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I want to encode query string to make it look like id hash. Like rewritten link.

Comment: Encoding != hash, so I hope you're not using this for security purposes!