# Convert decimal number to excel-header-like number

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf

```
0 = A
1 = B
...
25 = Z
26 = AA
27 = AB
...
701 = ZZ
702 = AAA
```

I cannot think of any solution that does not involve loop-bruteforce :-(

I expect a function/program, that accepts a decimal number and returns a string as a result.

Comment: Sounds like a base10 to base26 conversion problem...

Comment: @deceze: it just sounds, but it is not :-)

Comment: @deceze: because in number AA, for example, both chars doesn't mean the same digit, actually. They represent different ones. First one is equivalent of 1, and second is 0 ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Do you want `AA --> 26` conversion or `26 --> AA` ?

Comment: No, AA in base26 is equivalent to 26 in base10. I think you need to brush up your definition of [positional notation systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation). :)

Comment: @deceze: yep, exactly. I mean that this algorythm is not for "general" notation, but positional one (did not know this term)

Comment: You may be surprised to hear that our "general" notation *is* positional notation. :)

Comment: @deceze: uhm... If it is, then. `00000001 = 1` (dec), `00000000A = A` (hex), but `AAAAAAAAAB != B`. What is the difference then?!

Comment: Yes, ignore my ramblings, @Gareth you planed me... ^_^;;;;; It's too late in the day for me to get into these discussions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Golf: Numeric equivalent of an Excel column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634427/code-golf-numeric-equivalent-of-an-excel-column-name)

Comment: @mobrule: This is not a duplicate. This is decimal to excel. The one you posted was excel to decimal.

Comment: @codaddict See item #7 on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions/24258#24258. The standards for code-golf questions are lower.

Comment: This definition is a little off: I'm pretty sure that the column named "A" in Excel is numbered 1. And that is also the way the inverse code golf problem was designed. (Full admission: my solution gets a character shorter if 1->"A"!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Haskell, <strike>78</strike> <strike>57</strike> <strike>50</strike> 43 chars

```
o=map(['A'..'Z']:)$[]:o
e=(!!)$o>>=sequence
```

Other entries aren't counting the driver, which adds another 40 chars:

```
main=interact$unlines.map(e.read).lines
```

A new approach, using a lazy, infinite list, and the power of Monads!  And besides, using `sequence` makes me `:)`, using infinite lists makes me `:o`

Comment: You can use `fromEnum` instead of chr, which should be shorter.

Answer (score 4):

If you look carefully the excel representation is *like* base 26 number but **not** exactly same as base 26.

In Excel conversion `Z + 1 = AA` while in base-26 `Z + 1 = BA`

The algorithm is almost same as decimal to base-26 conversion with just once change.
In base-26, we do a recursive call by passing it the `quotient`, but here we pass it `quotient-1`:

```
function decimalToExcel(num)

        // base condition of recursion.
        if num < 26
                print 'A' + num 

        else                     
                quotient = num / 26;
                reminder = num % 26;

                // recursive calls.
                decimalToExcel(quotient - 1);
                decimalToExcel(reminder);
        end-if                       
end-function
```

[**Java Implementation**](http://www.ideone.com/k1iEp)

Comment: Uhm, I cannot agree it is a base 26 number. After you add 1 to any number you cannot get the total number that consists of same digits. `Z + 1 == AA`. This is impossible in "regular" bases.

Comment: @zerkms `9 + 1 = 10`. `Z + B = AA`, where (base26)B equals (base10)1. `Z + 1` is nonsense since that's mixing bases.

Comment: you would expect Z + B (1) == BA (10), surely?

Comment: @deceze: Since A=0 in the "real" base 26, AA is 0. Or rather, 00.

Comment: @Gareth: I expect that adding zeros (0 == A) before the number doesn't change its real value. But it is not true for excel-like notation.

Comment: @Gareth: and yes, that is why I don't think this excel-like numbers belongs to regular based (dec, hex, oct, etc) numbers.

Comment: @zerkms exactly, my comment was an explanation to @deceze :)

Comment: Downvoted because it is *not* a base 26 conversion. Excel headers are *not* real base 26.

Comment: @Quaternion Please do work it out for us in a separate answer, since, after much complaining from me to the contrary, this really *isn't*.

Comment: very sorry you're right I wrote that just before going to sleep it was the last thing I read before sleep funny how you wake up and think... Well I was completely wrong =)

Comment: Just to golf it up, `static String f(int n){return (char)((n%26)+65)+((n<26)?"":f(n/26-1));}`

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 44 chars

Oh c'mon, we can do better than lengths of 100+ :

```
X=lambda n:~n and X(n/26-1)+chr(65+n%26)or''
```

Testing:

```
>>> for i in 0, 1, 25, 26, 27, 700, 701, 702:
...     print i,'=',X(i)
...     
0 = A
1 = B
25 = Z
26 = AA
27 = AB
700 = ZY
701 = ZZ
702 = AAA
```

Comment: @gusbro: yes, it does. added them to the example

Answer (score 3):

Since I am not sure what base you're converting from and what base you want (your title suggests one and your question the opposite), I'll cover both.

## Algorithm for converting `ZZ` to `701`

First recognize that we have a number encoded in base 26, where the "digits" are `A..Z`. Set a counter `a` to zero and start reading the number at the rightmost (least significant digit). Progressing from right to left, read each number and convert its "digit" to a decimal number. Multiply this by 26<sup>`a`</sup> and add this to the result. Increment `a` and process the next digit.

## Algorithm for converting `701` to `ZZ`

We simply factor the number into powers of 26, much like we do when converting to binary. Simply take `num%26`, convert it to `A..Z` "digits" and append to the converted number (assuming it's a string), then integer-divide your number. Repeat until `num` is zero. After this, reverse the converted number string to have the most significant bit first.

**Edit:** As you point out, once two-digit numbers are reached we actually have base 27 for all non-least-significant bits. Simply apply the same algorithms here, incrementing any "constants" by one. *Should* work, but I haven't tried it myself.

**Re-edit:** For the `ZZ->701` case, don't increment the base exponent. Do however keep in mind that `A` no longer is 0 (but 1) and so forth.

## Explanation of why this is *not* a base 26 conversion

Let's start by looking at the real base 26 positional system. (Rather, look as base 4 since it's less numbers). The following is true (assuming A = 0):

```
 A = AA = A * 4^1 + A * 4^0 = 0 * 4^1 + 0 * 4^0 = 0
 B = AB = A * 4^1 + B * 4^0 = 0 * 4^1 + 1 * 4^0 = 1
 C = AC = A * 4^1 + C * 4^0 = 0 * 4^1 + 2 * 4^0 = 2
 D = AD = A * 4^1 + D * 4^0 = 0 * 4^1 + 3 * 4^0 = 3
     BA = B * 4^0 + A * 4^0 = 1 * 4^1 + 0 * 4^0 = 4
```

And so forth... notice that `AA` is 0 rather than 4 as it would be in Excel notation. Hence, Excel notation is *not* base 26.

Answer (score 3):

### In Excel VBA ... the obvious choice :)

```
Sub a()

  For Each O In Range("A1:AA1")
    k = O.Address()
    Debug.Print Mid(k, 2, Len(k) - 3); "="; O.Column - 1
  Next

End Sub
```

Or for getting the column number in the first row of the WorkSheet (which make more sense, since we are in Excel ...)

```
Sub a()

  For Each O In Range("A1:AA1")
    O.Value = O.Column - 1
  Next

End Sub
```

Or better yet:

## 56 chars

```
Sub a()
  Set O = Range("A1:AA1")
  O.Formula = "=Column()"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala: 63 chars

```
def c(n:Int):String=(if(n<26)""else c(n/26-1))+(65+n%26).toChar
```

Answer (score 1):

### Prolog, <strike>109</strike> 123 bytes

Convert from decimal number to Excel string:

```
c(D,E):- d(D,X),atom_codes(E,X).
d(D,[E]):-D<26,E is D+65,!.
d(D,[O|M]):-N is D//27,d(N,M),O is 65+D rem 26.
```

That code does not work for c(27, N), which yields N='BB'

This one works fine:

```
c(D,E):-c(D,26,[],X),atom_codes(E,X).
c(D,B,T,M):-(D<B->M-S=[O|T]-B;(S=26,N is D//S,c(N,27,[O|T],M))),O is 91-S+D rem B,!.
```

Tests:

```
?- c(0, N).
N = 'A'.


?- c(27, N).
N = 'AB'.

?- c(701, N).
N = 'ZZ'.

?- c(702, N).
N = 'AAA'
```

Converts from Excel string to decimal number (87 bytes):

```
x(E,D):-x(E,0,D).
x([C],X,N):-N is X+C-65,!.
x([C|T],X,N):-Y is (X+C-64)*26,x(T,Y,N).
```

Answer (score 1):

### F# : <strike>166</strike> 137

```
let rec c x  = if x < 26 then [(char) ((int 'A') + x)] else List.append (c (x/26-1)) (c (x%26))
let s x = new string (c x |> List.toArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP: At least 59 and 33 characters.

```
<?for($a=NUM+1;$a>=1;$a=$a/26)$c=chr(--$a%26+65).$c;echo$c;
```

Or the shortest version:

```
<?for($a=A;$i++<NUM;++$a);echo$a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following formula, you can figure out the last character in the string:

```
transform(int num)
    return (char)num + 47; // Transform int to ascii alphabetic char. 47 might not be right.

char lastChar(int num)
{
    return transform(num % 26);
}
```

Using this, we can make a recursive function (I don't think its brute force).

```
string getExcelHeader(int decimal)
{
    if (decimal > 26)
        return getExcelHeader(decimal / 26) + transform(decimal % 26);
    else
        return transform(decimal);
}
```

Or.. something like that. I'm really tired, maybe I should stop answering questions and go to bed :P

Comment: Nope, this will convert to real base 26, not the weird Excel base.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I'll be more careful :)

Comment: Even though this answer is not 100% correct, i don't think it deserves to be downvted (+1)