# in c#, how can i build up array from A to ZZ that is similar to the way that excel orders columns

Tags: c#, algorithm

i am looking for code that can generate an array where the first item is **A**, then **B**, then **C** . . .after **Z** it would then go to **AA**, then **AB** then **AC** . . .  all the way up to **ZZ**.

what is the best way of doing this in C#?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One of the ways is:

```
IEnumerable<string> generate()
{
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        yield return new string(c, 1);
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        for (char d = 'A'; d <= 'Z'; d++)
            yield return new string(new[] { c, d });
}
```

---

Edit:
you can actually produce "infinite" sequence (bounded by maximal `long` value) with somewhat more complicated code:

```
string toBase26(long i)
{
    if (i == 0) return ""; i--;
    return toBase26(i / 26) + (char)('A' + i % 26);
}

IEnumerable<string> generate()
{
    long n = 0;
    while (true) yield return toBase26(++n);
}
```

This one goes like that: A, B, ..., Z, AA, AB, ..., ZZ, AAA, AAB, ... etc:

```
foreach (var s in generate().Take(200)) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: This is so simple and elegant it's scary :)

Comment: I would return `new string(new [] {c, d})` in second case

Comment: @Snowbear: yes, your way is more elegant, I'll change it.

Comment: This is not Base 26, because `AA` is not the same as `A`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/programming-riddle-how-might-you-translate-an-excel-column-name-to-a-number where several answers also gave an inverse operation.

Comment: @Svante: yes, but it's quite close to. The name is slightly misleading, I agree. (The inverse operation is trivial as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Great answer of Vlad.

Here's another variation on that:

```
 static IEnumerable<string> generate() {
   for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
     yield return c.ToString();
   }

   foreach (string s in generate()) {
     for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
       yield return s + c;
     }
   }
 }
```

If you don't mind starting the sequence with an empty string you could write it as follows:

```
 static IEnumerable<string> generate() {
   yield return "";

   foreach (string s in generate()) {
     for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
       yield return s + c;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wow, nice infinite recursion usage! I wish I had invented this. It could be even simpler if replace the first loop with just `yield return "";`.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate numbers using `Enumerable.Range` and cast them to `char` to generate A-Z. Next step is to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in SO albeit in PHP. Would this help? [Algorithm to get the excel-like column name of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302857/algorithm-to-get-the-excel-like-column-name-of-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32('A'),26).Select( x => Convert.ToChar(x) );
var result = (
  q.Select( x => x.ToString() )
   .Concat( 
      q.SelectMany(
        x => q.Select( y => x.ToString() + y.ToString() )
      )
   )
);
```

Comment: Linq should be used to make code readable, not to make code Linqish

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine as a functional expression of what he was asking for. Vlad's is nicer to look at, true, but only because the compiler hides all the cruft it creates to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    public static string IntegerToExcelColumn(int col)
    {
        // I've put a 256 upper bound here because Excel 2003 
        // allows only 256 columns. Change it if you're using 
        // Excel 2007 or 2010.
        Debug.Assert(col >= 1 && col <= 256);

        if (col >= 1 && col <= 26)
        {
            return ((char)(((int)'A') + (col - 1))).ToString();
        }

        // I've put a 256 upper bound here because Excel 2003 
        // allows only 256 columns. Change it if you're using 
        // Excel 2007 or 2010.
        if (col > 26 && col <= 256)
        {
            int rem = col % 26;
            int pri = col / 26;
            if (rem == 0)
            {
                rem = 26;
                pri--;
            }
            char[] buffer = new char[2];
            buffer[0] = (char)(((int)'A') + (pri - 1));
            buffer[1] = (char)(((int)'A') + (rem - 1));
            return new string(buffer);
        }

        return "";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] columns= new string[255];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
            columns[i-1] = IntegerToExcelColumn(i);
        foreach(var col in columns)
            Console.WriteLine(col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. :)

```
string[] values =
  Enumerable.Range(0, 27 * 26)
  .Select(
    n => new String(
      new[] { (char)('@' + n / 26), (char)('A' + n % 26) },
      n < 26 ? 1 : 0, n < 26 ? 1 : 2
    )
  )
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and take note of the values of the characters. You should be able to work out a loop to increment the character from A to Z for as many times as you need to replicate the characters. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. A to ZZ

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int c=1;
        string cc=AtoZZ(c);
        for(int i=1;i<=702;i++){
        cc=AtoZZ(i);
        Console.WriteLine(cc);
        }
    }

    static string AtoZZ(int chr)
    {
        char c1;
        char c2;
        string alp = "";
        if(chr<=26)
        {
            c1 = (char)(chr + 64);
            alp = c1 + "";
        }        
        else
        {
            int cl1 = chr / 26;
            int cl2 = chr % 26;
            if(cl2==0){
                cl1--;
                cl2=26;
            }
            c1 = (char)(cl1 + 64);
            c2 = (char)(cl2 + 64);
            alp = c1 + "" + c2;
        }
        return alp;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Vlad's answer, here's the reverse operation of ToBase26(int):

```
static long ToBase10(string str)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return 0;
   var value = str[0] - 'A' + 1;

   return (long) (value * Math.Pow(26, str.Length - 1) + 
          ToBase10(str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1)));
}
```