# Looking up a value in a specified column

Tags: excel

Something I've wanted to do quite a bit lately, and can't work out how to do, is MATCH in a column I pass as an argument. Essentially, I have a two dimensional array, and I want to be able to find the first occurrence of a given value in the nth column, for any given value of n, and return the row number it occurs at. Alternatively (and more-or-less equivalently), I want to be able to search in the column with a given column header. Is there any way to do this?

Effectively, I want to simulate the non-existent function `=MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array,lookup_column,[match_type])`

I've kludged together a horrible bodge job using INDIRECT, which works, but offends me horribly. 
`=MATCH(lookup_value,INDIRECT("R"&<top of array>&"C"&<left of array>+<column reference>&":R"&<bottom of array>&"C"&<left of array>+<column reference>,FALSE),FALSE)`

Comment: what is that function supposed to return? the rownumber?

Comment: Yes, row number's what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula should work for you and will avoid INDIRECT.  Anytime you can avoid using Indirect, I recommend doing so.

`=MATCH(lookup_value,INDEX(lookup_array,0,MATCH(lookup_header,array_headers,0)),0)`

If you aren't looking up the column by column header and just have the column number, then it becomes easier:

`=MATCH(lookup_value,INDEX(lookup_array,0,column_number),0)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - I had no idea you could put 0 in the row section of INDEX and have it work like that! Thank you!

Comment: Can you also do `INDEX(lookup_array,row_number,0)` to return an entire row?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Set findCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").Find(What:="term_to_search")
```

Will select a header based on your search term.

```
Set range = ActiveSheet.Range(findCell, findCell.Offset(DEF_MAX_ROWS, 0))
```

Set up a range which will search from that header down a whole column.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it without scripting, if possible. Is there a way to do it with just cell formulae?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a range in a formula using the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd?CorrelationId=0bf26ce6-00c0-4e44-8552-cff005f7c7ab&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) function. So, for example, if you put the letter designation for the column you want to search in cell A75, you could use:

```
=MATCH("Value_To_Match", INDIRECT(A75 & ":" & A75), 0)
```

So, if the value in A75 is `G`, the string built up in the `INDIRECT` call is `G:G`, and the [`MATCH`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) will look through column G for "Value_To_Match" and return the row number in which it's found.

Using this idea, you can put a formula into A75 that generates  the column designation for the column you want to search. For example, if your column headers are all in row 1, and the header you want to search for is in A74, you can do:

```
=CHAR(MATCH(A74, 1:1, 0) + 64)
```

using the [`CHAR`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/char.php) function to convert numbers into ASCII characters, so 65 becomes A, 66 becomes B, etc. Note that this will only work if you don't have columns past Z. You'd need a more fussy formula to do the right thing with AA, etc.

You can overcome the annoyances of dealing with column letters by using [R1C1 notation](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EED883/YI416010881.htm) instead, which you can activate by adding a second parameter of `FALSE` to the `INDIRECT` expression. Now, instead of specifying your column by a letter, you'll specify it using a number. This simplifies the column-finder in A75:

```
=MATCH(A74, 1:1, 0)
```

and also the `INDIRECT` expression in your overall `MATCH`:

```
=MATCH("Value_To_Match", INDIRECT("C" & A75, FALSE), 0)
```

Comment: @pnuts, for that to work, you have to change your settings to use R1C1 in general, or Excel will thing you're specifying a single cell in Column C.

Comment: @pnuts If A2 contains the value 5, that INDIRECT will return a reference to Cell C5, not to Column 5, unless you [change your settings](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-do-i-change-the-r1c1-reference-style-to/5dd4aecc-f83b-476e-ac38-6769139502a0).

Comment: @pnuts, so, if you want to reference Cell C5 using A1 notation, how do you do it?

Comment: INDIRECT has an optional second argument. By default, it uses A1 notation, but it can be forced to use R1C1 notation. `INDIRECT("C5")` will reference cell C5, `INDIRECT("C5",0)` will reference column 5.

Comment: @TamCoton Thanks for pointing that out. I've incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For column references beyond `Z` you might switch notation (Excel Options, Formulas, Working with formulas and check R1C1 reference style) and, assuming the value to be looked up is in 'A1' (R1C1) with the column number in 'A2' (R2C1) apply:

```
  =MATCH(R1C1,INDIRECT("C"&R2C1,0),0)
```

to save some complexity in [converting a string of two or three characters into the relevant column number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/programming-riddle-how-might-you-translate-an-excel-column-name-to-a-number).

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a two dimensional array:  **B3:E17**  and we wish to locate *Happiness* in the third column of that array.
In **G1** enter:

B3:E17

In **G2** enter:

3

In **G3** enter:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(G1)),COLUMN(INDIRECT(G1))+$G$2-1) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(G1))+ROWS(INDIRECT(G1))-1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(G1))+$G$2-1)
```

This will display the address of that third column.  Then in **G4** enter:

```
=MATCH("Happiness",INDIRECT(G3),0)
```

For example:

[image]