# Get largest column name that come before a given column name in a list of Excel columns string

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

Please consider this lists:

```
var List1 = {};
var List2 = {"A"};
var List3 = {"AE"};
var List4 = {"A", "B", "F", "H", "AA", "AC", "AE"};
```

This lists are Excel Columns. Now I want to find column name that come before a given column name, for example if I want to find that which column come before "N" I want to get this results from lists:

```
null // From List 1
"A"  // From List 2
null // From List 3
"H"  // From List 4
```

How I can write a LINQ query that returns this result for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list is ordered, this is one possible way :

```
YourList.TakeWhile(o => ExcelToNumber(o) < ExcelToNumber("N"))
        .LastOrDefault();
```

---

`ExcelToNumber()` is a method to convert excel column name to integer, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1004624/2998271). I included the method definition below for easy reference, credit 100% to contributors of the linked post :

```
int ExcelToNumber(string x) {
    return x.Aggregate(0, (s, c) => s * 26 + c - 'A' + 1);
}
```